# Почему некорректно отображает views (sinatra)?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

В общем имею такую структуру:

```
get '/' do
end

# Одна публикация
get '/posts/:id' do 
end

# Форма для добавления публикации
get '/new' do
end

# Сохранение публикации
post '/posts' do
end

# Форма для редактировани публикации
get '/:id/edit' do
end

# Обновление отредактированной публикации
put '/posts/:id' do
end

# Стриница с предупреждением об удалении публикации
get '/posts/:id/delete' do
end
```

Проблема в том, что некорректно работает экшн с одной публикацией. Если убираю /posts и оставляю только /:id

```
# Одна публикация
get '/:id' do 
end
```

то все отображается прекрасно. Но не работают другие экшны. Естественно выходит ошибка:

```
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=new:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно.
Роуты же проверяются **в порядке определения**.
А обрабатывается запрос **первым подошедшим обработчиком**.

`/new` **подходит и под `/:id`**. И когда проверка на совпадение с `/:id` находится выше, то запрос на `/new` попадёт именно под обработчик `/:id`, а в обработчик `/new` попасть будет невозможно.

Путей для решения два, выбирайте любой:

- Изменить порядок, чтобы наиболее общие (вроде `/:id`) проверялись как можно позже и не мешали более специфичным роутам
- Наложить дополнительные условия, с помощью [условий](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Conditions) или просто регулярки.

Comment: спасибо, помогло. Кто бы мог подумать, что решение такое простое