# CRUD app Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте! Появилась необходимость изучения ror. Мне необходимо в админской части приложения иметь возможность создавать удлять и т.д. страницы сайта, открывать закрывать к ним доступ, добавлять описание. Я создал модеть Page, контроллер с методами new, destroy, update и т.д, страницы создаются, могу посмотреть список страниц, удалить, вывести в меню по средствам перебора массива, перейти на страницу по ссылке вида /pages/1 и т.д. Собственно вопрос, как или можно ли вообще создать для каждой страницы свой шаблон? роут? Например я создаю страницу Contactns, перейти на нее я могу по ссылке /pages/1, а хотелось бы чтобы она имела свой роут и шаблон, например sitename/about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно. Вы можете пользоваться при определении маршрутов обычными хелперами, которые в себе содержат кучу предположений и типичных решений за вас. Для обычного CRUD вы, скорее всего, пользовались хелпером `resources` с [настройками по умолчанию](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Но пользоваться им необязательно (особенно если вам нужно обозначть всего один-два маршрута). И если пользоваться, то необязательно без каких-либо изменений в настройках.

В простейшем случае, вам может быть достаточно для просмотра одного GET-маршрута:

```
get ':site_name/:name', to: 'pages#show'
```

...а в `show` ищите страницу по `params[:site_name]` и `params[:name]`.

...но имейте в виду, что маршруты проверяются **в порядке определения**, и под этот шаблон подойдёт и `params/1`. Поэтому если у вас есть роуты такого вида, разместите их **выше**, иначе [будут приколы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/593839/181100).

Шаблон [можно определить уже в контроллере](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html#method-i-action_has_layout-3F), создав метод, возвращающий на основе `params` (или `request`, если не хватило) строку, по которой будет искаться шаблон.

```
class WeblogController < ActionController::Base
  layout :writers_and_readers # layout :метод

  def index
    # ...
  end

  private

  def writers_and_readers
    logged_in? ? "writer_layout" : "reader_layout"
  end
end
```